# Exclude SockJs Websocket Url Form SecurityFilterChain

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

Hi guys I am using keycloak auth by 0auth2 and was able to authenticate every other endpoint expect for my websockect endpoint I am getting 401 for my websocket endpoint and sockjs does not allow to append headers. So My query is how can I remove this endpoint from my authentication I tried request matches but it's not working for me-

My security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().configurationSource(request -> {
            CorsConfiguration cors = new CorsConfiguration();
             String originHeader = request.getHeader("Origin");
                cors.addAllowedOriginPattern(originHeader);
                cors.applyPermitDefaultValues();
                //cors.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
                cors.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET","POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
                cors.addAllowedHeader("*");
                cors.setAllowCredentials(true);
                
                return cors;
        }).and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers("/ws/**").permitAll()
                       .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(
                    jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(customJwtConverter())
            ));
        return http.build();
        
        
    }

    @Bean
    public Converter<Jwt, CustomJwt> customJwtConverter() {
        return new CustomJwtConverter();
    }
```

My websocket config-

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    
     private final KeycloakSpringBootProperties configuration;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws") .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200").withSockJS();
       // registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS().setWebSocketEnabled(true);
    }
    
    
}
```

My Angular request-

```
connectToWebSocket() {
    let ws = new SockJS(this.webSocketEndPoint,); //'http://localhost:8085/ws'
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
    const _this = this;
  const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', '' + sessionStorage.getItem('KeyToken'));

  
      console.log("token web"+JSON.stringify(headers))
      _this.stompClient.connect( {Authorization:headers}, function (frame: any) {
      
    });
  }
```